# (LocalDb)\Server_name showing error in connection string in Visual Studio 2017

Tags: mysql, sql-server, visual-studio, ado.net

I am making a simple console application in Visual Studio 2017 using ADO.net. I am using SQL Server Management Studio to manage and create tables, and using ADO.Net just to connect to the database and insert, modify or delete data on the database.

This is what I've written:

```
string cs = "Data Source=(LocalDb)\LocalSERVER;Initial Catalog=PlayerAuction;Integrated Security=True";

SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(cs);

SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO PLAYERS VALUES(@PlayerName,@BattingAvg,@BowlingAvg)", conn);
```

As I'm using ADO.Net I'm writing a connection string where in the Data Source, I have mentioned the (LocalDb)\LocalSERVER as my LocalDb instance. It is throwing an error. I have tried connecting to the database in Tools and copied the connection string there, It is not working as well.

This is the error I'm getting:

[image]

I have re checked the connection string properly.

This is the database connection:

[image]

Connection String as shown:

[image]

Please help me with this. Thank You.

Comment: Please don't include code as image

Comment: Why have you tagged mysql?

Comment: Please indent your code properly so it's readable

Comment: Can you try: `string cs = @"Data Source=(LocalDb)\LocalSERVER;Initial Catalog=PlayerAuction;Integrated Security=True";`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The back-slash is causing the problem. Try either:

```
string cs = @"Data Source=(LocalDb)\LocalSERVER;Initial Catalog=PlayerAuction;Integrated Security=True";
```

or

```
string cs = "Data Source=(LocalDb)\\LocalSERVER;Initial Catalog=PlayerAuction;Integrated Security=True";
```